# Shimano Metrea ST-U5060-R compatibility

Tags: shimano, derailleur, shifter, compatibility

So I'm trying to find out if [Shimano Metrea ST-U5060-R](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/metrea-u5000/ST-U5060-R.html) would be compatible with any Shimano 11 rear derailleur?

Also, would it also be compatible with the T4700 Tiagra derailleur since it seems to be using a 11 gear pull ratio (even though it's a 10 speed derailleur).

Or do you really need to stick with the [Shimano Metrea derailleur](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/metrea-u5000/RD-U5000-SS.html) in order to use that shifter?

Same question with the front derailleur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shimano compatibility charts say that Mattrea ST-U5060 is compatible with RD- R9000 (Dura Ace), R8000 (Ultegra) and R7000 (105) front and rear derailleurs.

Here are the compatibility charts -

Rear drivetrain: http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com/3.7?cid=C-453&acid=C-454

Front drivetrain: http://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com/3.7?cid=C-453&acid=C-455

Unsurprisingly according to Shimano Tiagra 4700 appears to only be compatible with itself. However, if someone has tried Tiagra derailleurs with 105 or Ultegra shifters (or vice versa) and knows it works, then Matrea shifters will work too.

Comment: according to this article https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1339/bicycle-rear-shifter-compatibility/, it should be compatible, but I don't know if it was really tested.

Comment: @kokito If Shimano's documentation says two parts are compatible, you can pretty much be assured that they'll not only work together, they'll work well together.  Shimano's compatibility statements are notoriously conservative, and you can usually go outside of what Shimano says "works" and get good results, such as using an 11-32 cassette with a derailleur that only officially supports an 11-30.

Comment: on yeah, I meant about Tiagra 4700

Comment: 4700 is said to use the Shimano 11 speed road derailleur actuation ratio (1.4:1) when all other 10 and below use the classic 1.7:1 ratio. That's probably true - but that's just for the *rear* derailleur. I've never read anything about front derailleur compatibility.